# Angular 2 I don't know how to delete a row of a pushed Object

Tags: arrays, typescript, angular

First let me be clear about my problem/issue:

First it was like this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/92z2oe7f4w5x2b5/conditions.jpg?dl=0 Here it deletes the last created Object in my case Conditions.

but i want to delete each condition separately like this see the red box next to each row: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ptwq6sk6da4p21k/new.jpg?dl=0

```
import {Component, OnInit, DynamicComponentLoader, Input} from 'angular2/core';
import {Condition}    from './condition';

import {DateCondition}    from './datecondition.component';
import {StringCondition}    from './stringcondition.component';
import {SelectCondition}    from './selectcondition.component';
import {ConditionDetailComponent}    from './conditiondetail.component';

import {ConditionService} from './condition.service'

@Component({
    selector: 'condition-builder',
    templateUrl: 'app/conditionbuilder.component.html',
    directives: [ConditionDetailComponent],
})

export class ConditionBuilderComponent implements OnInit {
    conditions: Condition[] = [];
    catalog: Condition[] = [];

constructor(public _conditionService: ConditionService) { }

getConditions() {
    this._conditionService.getConditions().then(conditions => this.catalog = conditions);
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.getConditions();
}

onChange(conditionsIndex, selectedCondition:string): void {
    this.conditions[conditionsIndex] = this.catalog.find(condition => condition.name == selectedCondition);
}

newCondition() {
    this.conditions.push(this.catalog[0]);
}

deleteCondition() {
    this.conditions.pop();
}
}
```

In the code above i'll import the getConditions with the object of conditions in my case. Does any one know how i do this and what is the best way to handle this issue?

Here i want to

```
import {Component, OnInit, Input, DynamicComponentLoader, ElementRef} from 'angular2/core';

import {Condition}    from './condition';

import {DateCondition}    from './datecondition.component';
import {StringCondition}    from './stringcondition.component';
import {SelectCondition}    from './selectcondition.component';
import {ConditionBuilderComponent} from "./conditionbuilder.component";

@Component({
    selector: 'condition-detail',
    template: '<div #child></div>'
    + '<a class="btn btn-danger" (click)="deleteCondition()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i></a>'
})

export class ConditionDetailComponent implements OnInit  {
    @Input() condition: Condition;

    dcl:DynamicComponentLoader;
    elementRef:ElementRef;

    constructor(dcl: DynamicComponentLoader, elementRef: ElementRef) {
        this.dcl = dcl;
        this.elementRef = elementRef;
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.dcl.loadIntoLocation(this.condition, this.elementRef, 'child');
    }

   deleteCondition() {
    HOW CAN I DELETE THE CONDITION ROW HERE?
}
```

Like this is the code build, ill hope it is clear for you to help me out. How does the deleteCondition method know which row he needs to deleten and how do i delete it out of the array in the code above the page?

Ill hope someone can help me out!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could provide the list to the sub component and remove the current element from it. This way the associated component in the loop will be removed.

- The main component:

  ```
  @Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
      <div *ngFor="#elt of data">
        <my-component [elt]="elt" [data]="data"></my-component>
      </div>
    `,
    directives: [MyComponent]
  })
  export class AppComponent {
    constructor() {
      this.data = [
        {name: 'name1'},
        {name: 'name2'},
        {name: 'name3'},
        {name: 'name4'}
      ];
    }
  }
  ```
- The child component:

  ```
  @Component({
    selector: 'my-component',
    template: `
      <div>{{elt.name}} <span (click)="delete()">X</span></div>
    `
  })
  export class MyComponent {
    @Input()
    elt: any;

    @Input()
    data: any[];

    delete() {
      var index = this.data.indexOf(this.elt);
      this.data.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }
  ```

See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/o5O0Rr?p=preview.

Comment: So i'll pass the value's of the array trough the inputs

Comment: I don't think this best approach. You can use `EventEmitter` to notify a parent about deletion. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html